# initializing a new struct in c

Tags: c, syntax, struct

I have tried to initialise a new struc in c.

What's wrong with my syntax ?

```
    AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *context;

   //check if icons need to be downloaded
   if (pEntity->cBigIcon[0] != 0){
      if (res_get(RES_BITMAP,RES_SKIN, pEntity->cBigIcon) == NULL){

          context = {pEntity->iID, pEntity->cBigIcon};
          //context->Icon = pEntity->cBigIcon;
          //context->iID = pEntity->iID;

         res_download(RES_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, pEntity->cBigIcon, NULL, "",TRUE, 1, addressItem_icon_download_callback, context );
      }
   }
```

I get syntax error for this as well:

```
    AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *context = {0,NULL};

   //check if icons need to be downloaded
   if (pEntity->cBigIcon[0] != 0){
      if (res_get(RES_BITMAP,RES_SKIN, pEntity->cBigIcon) == NULL){

          //context = {pEntity->iID, pEntity->cBigIcon};
          context->Icon = pEntity->cBigIcon;
          context->iID = pEntity->iID;

         res_download(RES_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, pEntity->cBigIcon, NULL, "",TRUE, 1, addressItem_icon_download_callback, context );
      }
   }

   if (pEntity->cSmallIcon[0] != 0){
      if (res_get(RES_BITMAP,RES_SKIN, pEntity->cSmallIcon) == NULL){

          //context = {pEntity->iID, pEntity->cSmallIcon};
          context->Icon = pEntity->cSmallIcon;
          context->iID = pEntity->iID;

         res_download(RES_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, pEntity->cSmallIcon, NULL, "",TRUE, 1, addressItem_icon_download_callback, context );
      }
   }
```

then this (3) should work?

```
 AddressItem_Callback_ContextType context = {0,NULL};

   //check if icons need to be downloaded
   if (pEntity->cBigIcon[0] != 0){
      if (res_get(RES_BITMAP,RES_SKIN, pEntity->cBigIcon) == NULL){

          //context = {pEntity->iID, pEntity->cBigIcon};
          context.Icon = pEntity->cBigIcon;
          context.iID = pEntity->iID;

         res_download(RES_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, pEntity->cBigIcon, NULL, "",TRUE, 1, addressItem_icon_download_callback, context );
      }
   }

   if (pEntity->cSmallIcon[0] != 0){
      if (res_get(RES_BITMAP,RES_SKIN, pEntity->cSmallIcon) == NULL){

          //context = {pEntity->iID, pEntity->cSmallIcon};
          context.Icon = pEntity->cSmallIcon;
          context.iID = pEntity->iID;

         res_download(RES_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, pEntity->cSmallIcon, NULL, "",TRUE, 1, addressItem_icon_download_callback, context );
      }
   }
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory to it and set each memeber value with `=` operator(as you did in comments)

Comment: correct it as: `AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *context = NULL;`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I have tried this at the beginning and got an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
context = {pEntity->iID, pEntity->cBigIcon};
```

`{}` initializer list can only be used at declaration time, it cannot be used in an assignment expression.

You have to break this down in two assignment statements (and for this you'll also have to initialize the uninitialized `context` pointer).

Comment: Will it matter that `context` is a pointer not structure itself. I mean can initializer lists be used with pointers?

Comment: @PaulR I was thinking the same, but was confused.

Comment: @ouah how should I write this when I have few `if` statements? like in my second code section?

Comment: @EladBenda `AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *context = {0,NULL};` You also cannot do this. `context` is a pointer to a structure object, not a structure object.

Comment: @EladBenda Allocate memory for your structure: `AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *context = malloc(sizeof *context);` and use assignment statements to initialize / modify the structure members: `context->Icon = /*...*/; context->iID = /* ... */;`

Answer (score 2):

As ouah says initializers must be used at declaration time, but in C99 you can make use of compound literals:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct st {
    int a, b;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct st *t;

    t = &(struct st){1, 2};
    printf("%d %d\n", t->a, t->b);
    return 0;
}
```

in your case

```
context = &(struct AddressItem_Callback_ContextType){pEntity->iID, pEntity->cBigIcon};
```

Comment: That's C99, [take a look](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404)